# Ubuntu 22.04 WSL 2 has problem rendering characters

Tags: command-line, 22.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, locale, character-set

I have enabled WSL on my Windows Version 10.0.19043.1889, installed Ubuntu Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. After installation, WSL was set on version 1:

```
wls -l -v
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-22.04    Running         1
```

Then, I converted the Ubuntu to WSL version 2:

```
wsl --set-default-version 2
wsl --shutdown
wsl --set-version Ubuntu-22.04 2
```

After conversion to version 2, the Ubuntu 22.04 App does not render the character properly:

```
gstef@AHERDSKGSTEF01:~$ ls
''$'\001\020''3@pu'$'\001''@8'$'\r''@'$'\036\035\006\004''@@@�'$'\002''�'$'\002\b\003\004\030\003\030\003\030\003\034\034\001\001\004''�'$'\037''�'$'\037\020\001\005'
```

[Ubuntu 22.04 App terminal output for ls command at home directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y8Hu.png)

Not the ls command is executed at home directory ~. If execute ls on a Windows drive /mnt/c/ then character rendering is correct:

```
gstef@AHERDSKGSTEF01:/mnt/c$ ls
ls: cannot access 'DumpStack.log.tmp': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'hiberfil.sys': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'pagefile.sys': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'swapfile.sys': Permission denied
'$GetCurrent'              DumpStack.log.tmp  'Program Files'         SWSetup                      WINDOWS
'$RECYCLE.BIN'             Intel              'Program Files (x86)'   SYSTAG.BIN                   bootTel.dat
```

[Ubuntu 22.04 App terminal output for ls command at windows C: drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HUkR.png)

I am somewhat sure that with Ubuntu 22.04 and WSL version 1, then rendering of the characters was correct.

Note that my Windows language is set to Japanese, but locale is default English, if I understand it correctly

```
gstef@AHERDSKGSTEF01:~$ locale
LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Anybody an idea, if the wrong character rendering is related to conversion to WSL 2 or if is a matter of locale settings?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I removed Ubuntu 22.04 App, set WSL by default to 2 `wsl --set-default-version 2` and re-installed the Ubuntu 22.04 App. This solved my problem and character output seems to be ok for now. (Of course, I lost all my data during this process, which I could afford, because it was a fresh installation.)